# PHP prevent MySQL race condition

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to prevent users joining at the "same time" from selecting the same available admin.

What i'm doing is:

```
$conn->beginTransaction();

$sth = $conn->query("SELECT admin,room FROM admins WHERE live = 1 AND available = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE");
$free_admin = $sth->fetch();

if (!empty($free_admin)) {

  $conn->query("UPDATE admins SET available = 0 WHERE room = " . $free_admin['room']);

  .
  .

  $conn->commit();

} else {

  $conn->rollBack();
}
```

Unfortunately it's not really working. When there is a high traffic, many users end up selecting the same free admin which causes an issue.

How can i lock a SELECTED row so i can read it and update it by only one user before any other user can read it?

Comment: You should look at binding dynamic values with [bindValue/bindParam](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @Chris Ya i will, this code is just for testing to overcome the race condition issue

Comment: @e4c5 I'm not sure i understand your question. What I'm trying to do is select a random available admin. If there is one, set him as unavailable. How can this be done better?

Comment: Oops sorry, I misread your question. (you haven't actually made it very easy to read)

Comment: What does a `SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;` query tell you

Comment: @e4c5 both have the same value of "REPEATABLE-READ"

Comment: repeatable read should be ok. What else are you doing in that transaction block? Does your PHP code change the isolation level at any point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124274/discussion-between-tarekhoury-and-e4c5).

Answer (score 0):

In the updatestatement, use

```
 WHERE room = ... AND availabe = 1
```

After the query, check mysql affected_rows to verify you did change the availability succesfully, and if not, restart.

Comment: I got the idea behind your solution. I have tired it, unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: did you verify you had an affected_row? And retried the select if you had none? If so, it cannot be that some other process stole it from you  (Unless you use some form of caching or slave database)